# CONCAT values in MySQL query to ignore NULL values

Tags: php, mysql

I want to CONCAT the values in 8 fields (sp, lp, gp, sr, zd, md, pr, rs), and return the result as "chemistry". The problem is that any one record will only have two (maybe three or four) values out of the 8 possible, the remaining values will be NULL. Furthermore, if the value is NULL, I want neither the preceding text (SP:, LP:, GP:, SR:, etc...), nor the (line break) to be displayed.

From my research on here I've come across CONCAT_WS(), and IFNULL(). I will need help implementing these functions, in order to achieve my desired result.

```
    CONCAT(
      'SP: ', sp, '<br />',
      'LP: ', lp, '<br />',
      'GP: ', gp, '<br />',
      'SR: ', sr, '<br />',
      'ZD: ', zd, '<br />',
      'MD: ', md, '<br />',
      'PR: ', pr, '<br />',
      'RS: ', rs
    ) AS chemistry
```

Comment: It is a good practice to separate the Model logic from the Controller logic from the View logic (c.f. [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)). This is maybe the worst example of putting view logic into the db query I've ever seen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
CONCAT(
  IF (sp IS NULL, '', CONCAT('SP: ', sp, '<br />')),
  IF (lp IS NULL, '', CONCAT('LP: ', lp, '<br />')),
  IF (gp IS NULL, '', CONCAT('GP: ', gp, '<br />')),
  IF (sr IS NULL, '', CONCAT('SR: ', sr, '<br />')),
  IF (zd IS NULL, '', CONCAT('ZD: ', zd, '<br />')),
  IF (md IS NULL, '', CONCAT('MD: ', md, '<br />')),
  IF (pr IS NULL, '', CONCAT('PR: ', pr, '<br />')),
  IF (rs IS NULL, '', CONCAT('RS: ', rs))
) AS chemistry
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use two facts here: first, [**CONCAT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) (as many other SQL functions) returns `NULL` if any argument is `NULL`; second, [**CONCAT_WS**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) will just skip `NULL` values.

That makes the query as simple as...

```
CONCAT_WS('<br />',
   CONCAT('SP:', sp),
   CONCAT('LP:', lp),
   ...
) AS chemistry
```

---

Having said all this, I really wonder is it necessary to make this formatting at the query (database) level. First, using `<br />` to separate elements is really just a detail of representation - and it is subject to change far more often than you'd like it to. Second, it might be far easier both to write and adjust this code at application level - by using loops, for example.

Comment: That's good point about formatting at the query level vs the application level. I'm just a beginner, so I appreciate any and all advice that you give me.

Comment: That's ok, it's never too late to learn - as this very answer proves. )

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this, where you concatenate each element and compare to `NULL` (I prefer `COALESCE()` because it is ANSI standard):

```
CONCAT(
  coalesce(concat('SP: ', sp, '<br />'), ''),
  coalesce(concat('LP: ', lp, '<br />'), ''),
  coalesce(concat('GP: ', gp, '<br />'), ''),
  coalesce(concat('SR: ', sr, '<br />'), ''),
  coalesce(concat('ZD: ', zd, '<br />'), ''),
  coalesce(concat('MD: ', md, '<br />'), ''),
  coalesce(concat('PR: ', pr, '<br />'), ''),
  coalesce(concat('RS: ', rs, '<br />'), '')
) AS chemistry;
```

The problem is the final `'<br />'`.  I just added it onto all the rows, including the last.  If you really don't want it, then my advice is to remove it afterwards, but that can be a bit challenging.

Comment: Using `CONCAT_WS` with setting missing elements to `NULL` is beneficial in this case (to get rid off the final `<br />`).

Answer (score 0):

It'll be messy, but you can always do this:

```
CONCAT(
  ...
  IF(gp IS NULL, '', CONCAT('GP:', gp, '<br/>')),
  ...
)
```

Now keep in mind having HTML in your query is usually a sign you've got your concerns confused. The database should be concerned with data, not presentation.

Comment: Good point, how would you suggest I present this data, after I've queried it?

Comment: You're using PHP which can surely transform it for you as required. You should be focusing on getting the data values out of your database in their raw format, then formatting it in a second pass. If you go down the road you're on, soon you'll see madness like `SELECT CONCAT('<div style="float:left" class="tbl tbl_value">', ...)`